# Can't PaintCell after using QItemDelegate to change date position for a QCalendarWidget

Tags: python, pyside2, qitemdelegate, qcalendarwidget

I am trying to override QCalendarWidget's paintCell() method to paint a red outline on today's date cell and draw events that will be defined by the user. For my calendar, I used a QItemDelegate to change the alignment of the date flags so I would have more room to draw events. However, I can't seem to get both the QItemDelegate and paintCell() working together. I can only have one or the other work at one time. If I try to do both, only the Delegate shows and nothing is painted.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QCalendarWidget, QApplication, QItemDelegate, QTableView
from PySide2.QtGui import QPen
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.calendar = CustomCalendar()
        self.calendarview = self.calendar.findChild(QTableView, "qt_calendar_calendarview")
        self.calendardelegate = CalendarItemDelegate(self.calendarview)
        self.calendarview.setItemDelegate(self.calendardelegate)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.calendar)
        self.show()


class CustomCalendar(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setColor(Qt.red)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        if date == date.currentDate():
            painter.save()
            painter.drawRect(rect.adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1))
            painter.restore()


class CalendarItemDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter._date_flag = index.row() > 0
        super().paint(painter, option, index)

    def drawDisplay(self, painter, option, rect, text):
        if painter._date_flag:
            option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignLeft
        super().drawDisplay(painter, option, rect, text)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

How can I get both to work at once?

[image]

Delegate

[image]

PaintCell

Answer (score 1):

When a custom item delegate is set on the calendar widget, the default `paintCell` is just ignored, as it's responsibility of the (private) delegate to call it.

Since you're using a QItemDelegate, you can take advantage of the [`drawFocus()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#drawFocus) function and check if the `option.state` has the [`State_Selected`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StateFlag-enum) flag set (technically, you could do it in the `drawDisplay()` too, since the function is called anyway and the option has the same values):

```
    def drawFocus(self, painter, option, rect):
        super().drawFocus(painter, option, rect)
        if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            painter.save()
            painter.setPen(Qt.red)
            painter.drawRect(rect.adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1))
            painter.restore()
```

Comment: Calling paintCell from the delegate interests me. How could I do that?

Comment: Qt does that by using an internal delegate: it has a reference to the calendar widget, so it gets the date using the current month, the row, and the column, then calls `paintCell()` with the painter, the `option.rect` and the date computed before.

Comment: @Streeter do note that the `paintCell` *actually* calls back the delegate painting, so it doesn't make a lot of sense. What you could do, instead, is to find out if the current index *is* the current date. It's a bit tricky, but it can be done by reimplementing in python the original C++ implementation.